# How to replace backslash in R?

Tags: r

I have one string having 2 backslash followed by '%' symbol and i need to replace one in R.

```
x<-"70\\% marks obtained"
x<-sub("\\%","\%",x)

Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\%"
```

How can i do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That is one backslash. Namely, `\\` is one backslash inside of a string, since the backslash already escapes the backslash! To see with your own eyes, try:

```
cat(x)
```

instead of

```
print(x)
```

which will show the one backslash (`print` will display two because it's wrapped in quotes and needs to be escaped).

Comment: I know but i am using this in Sweave so it is treated as end of row so i want to change it to one backslash.

Comment: Maybe you should actually describe your actual problem then so we don't have to guess what you're trying to do...

Comment: Then try `gsub("\\\\", "\\", x, fixed = TRUE)`